# PHP - is there a way to put a variable in $_POST[]?

Tags: php, variables, post

Is there a way to get `$_POST['msg']` (where name='msg' is coming over from a form) to be `$_POST[$newstring]` (where `$newstring = $string;` and `$string = $_POST['msg'];`?

`$_POST[$newstring]` doesn't work. Is there a way to put a variable in `$_POST[]`?

I really am looking to get an answer to this exact question specifically. What I'm trying to accomplish is only to pass a variable into `$_POST[]` from a form. I am looking for straightforward answer, yes or no.

If yes, how to format it (e.g. `$_POST[$variable]` or `$_POST['$variable']` or `$_POST["$variable"]` or some other such way).

Comment: I don't understand what you want, but it sounds like you're opening yourself up to some security issues... Let's be clear here: form elements with a **name** posted to a script with `method="post"` will be available to that script in the `$_POST` superglobal. Do some basic debugging of `$_POST` on a form post to see what you've got and deal with it then, or give us some examples of what you want specifically.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['newstring'] = $_POST['msg'];
```

Remember that $_POST is an associative array of variables passed via the HTTP POST method. But like any array, you can modify it like so:

```
$arr[key] = value;
```

Where `key` is a string or integer. More info on PHP arrays can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You can read/assign from $_POST the way you would any array, because functionally it IS an associative array.

```
$string = $_POST['msg'];
$newstring = 'this is the new value';
$_POST['msg'] = $newstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax for pass the data form yore HTML file to php.

**In the HTML PART:**

```
         Call a function with this parameter with message containing html element.

         <input type="textbox" name="msg" onclick="post_msgto_php(this)">
```

**script**

```
     In the script part define the post_msgto_php(this) function with a Ajax post type to your php.

      try this .js code:

      function post_msgto_php(my_msg)
               {
                var msg=my_msg.name;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "your_post_msg.php"
                    data:{msg:msg},                                             
                    dataType:'JSON',

                    success:function(data){

                                 if(data.response=="success")

                                }
                });
               }
```

**your_post_msg.php :**

```
              Here send back a json response=>success  usig json_encode()

              <?php



                  $_POST['newstring'] = $_POST['msg'];

                   $data=array("response"=>"success");
                   json_encode($data);




              ?>
```